# ArcGIS Network Analyst Creating Service Areas Beyond Network?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, network-analyst

I am experiencing weird off shoots which are beyond  my network when creating service areas using Network Analyst. The red circle in the picture below shows an example. I am currently using ArcGIS 10.0 SP5.

[ArcGIS 10 Network Analyst Service Area Problem/Peculiarity with Solving](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20445), but did not have an answer beyond using detailed polygons instead of generalized polygons.

Where might this error come from?

Perhaps it is due to a dirty/poor network or a peculiarity within the calculation of generalized polygons.

[image]

Comment: I get these issues is my services areas sometimes too and would like to know why it is happening.